# C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, c++14

The application depends on a 3rd party library. While running it in debug mode, in Qt Creator with microsoft compiler, it stops showing the following message:

[image]

Looking at the code I see it is pointing to a line that calls `SetSomething` library's  function.

And on Application Output I see:

```
Exception at 0x7ffae24e4f69, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in YLibDllName!YTifFormat::SetSomething
```

Is this enough to say there is a problem on 3rd party library?

How should I deal with this kind of problem?

What this exception message is telling me? What are the probable causes?

Comment: No, it's not enough. You should fix the problem or find someone else to do it for you.

Comment: *Is this enough to say there is a problem on 3rd party library?* -- No.  The way to determine if this is a problem, provide the author(s) of the library with a very simple example, basically a skeleton program that does almost nothing *except* call the library's functions.  That's what the author(s) would probably want from you.  If you give them a full-blown program with all sorts of bells and whistles, then the issue could be *your* code, and not the library.